# How can I redirect back from https to http URL's after I removed a SSL certificate of let's encrypt in apache2 & nginx

Tags: server, apache2, nginx, ssl, letsencrypt

I configured a certificate of let's encrypt using certbot-auto and the https worked but when I was trying to remove the certificate of my domain using
certbot-auto delete... my wordpress and phpmyadmin site stopped being recognized, it keeps redirecting to https and it gives an error
404 can't reach this page but the apache2 and nginx index page could be reached...

I already did all of that cleared the cache, history, cookies, checked the mysql database it's on http:// but still redirects it to https:// and says it can't reach the page... I need to check for something in the deeper level, but I don't know what to check I tried to delete the ssl.confs that were made by let's encrypt but still 0 results

I need help re-configuring my servers back to the http redirect from the https redirect of the certificate configuration
What are the processes needed to be done in order to turn it back to http redirect?
Thanks for your help...

Comment: Which are you using, apache2 or nginx?

Comment: @rtaft Thanks for the reply, it's both one on each domain and it has the same results on both of them

Comment: So 2 different servers, one running apache and one running nginx?

Comment: @rtaft Yup... it's exactly the case

Comment: nginx config is usually in  `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`, probably a file called `default`.  Certbot adds a server section at the end of the file, in it there is a line `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;`  You can comment out the entire server section that has that entry.

Comment: @rtaft actually, I deleted all the server section of SSL certbot but it still didn't make any change, could it be something else? and what should I do about the apache2 server?...

Comment: It makes changes to the main server section as well `listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot`  You will need to remove those and put a `listen 80` in there.

Comment: @rtaft I did it also... still I get the same result... when you add the certificate it notifies that it added .conf in the letsencrypt folder and added some changes on httpd.conf so I deleted those files and it made the website download the page instead of showing it so I added those files back

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for their effort to help... I found the problem... there was a redirection in the default.conf and I deleted it and now everything works if it can help someone else I would be very glad